# Would forwarding traffic from a different location prevent attacks?

Tags: networking, security, port-forwarding, iptables

I was playing with iptables and decided to forward my port 80 to another server. That worked perfectly, of course, so the traffic was forwarded to the actual web server.

I was thinking, though - the VPS that the traffic is forwarded from is DDoS protected. Upon a DDoS attack, would the forwarding mean the traffic would not impact the server forwarded to as long as it doesn't exceed the maximum scrubbing capacity of the forwarding server?

So: when the forwarding server is attacked, will the server that's forwarded to be hit?

Answer (score 0):

The DDoS protection almost certainly takes place prior to the forwarding. So no, the server will not be hit.

Answer (score 0):

Idea here is the next: when your server is under attack it will consume a lot of recources so it could be problematic even to log in, check logs and run any commands to prevent attack. Having forwarding server in front of will allow you to see traffic goes and block attack.
Also usual forwarding traffic consumes less resources so you could place several web servers and use forwarding server as load-balancer.